# Change user id of all running process without stopping them

Tags: unix, process, permissions

I have presently all my process running by `user1` id on my server . Now we have a new user `user2` and we want all the process running by `user1` to run by `user2`. This is done for consistency as all other host uses `user2` What should be the things that i should follow and must do things ? Note that `user1` and `user2` both have root privileges. Number of processes running currenyly from `user1` is say almost half of all process running on the server.

Comment: This is a wierd question.  Use the tool (like useradd -l  <newnamehere>) on your system  to modify users.  This changes just the name not the numeric uid. You will have to review all of your startup files and change them - then reboot.  Good Luck - you will need it.

Comment: So is the only way of doing it to stop all the process and start them from new user id ?

Comment: I actually would not do that, but it does answer your question.  @DanField gave you a better functional answer.  With the exception that some services may not be restartable without a reboot.

Comment: When you say some services , you mean which kind of services ? Because in my case `user1` has root privileges and so will `user2` will have. It was used to run most process including cronjobs etc

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just rename `user1` as @jimmcnamara is suggesting?

Comment: Its just that i am wondering `user2` is already on other host but then on this host and the files are transfered from this host to host which already have `user2` So i believe just change of name would not serve purpose as user id number may differ for the same host `user2` on different host.

Comment: You did not mention file ownership - or I did not see it.    File ownership is based on a UID - a number.  IF.  If user1 (on the other systems) has the same uid as does user2, then renaming user2 will work as I suggested.  Otherwise no.  You will have to create an all-new user1, then reassign/restart all of the services.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.  A process can call `setuid()` itself, but trying to change the user identity on a running process could have disastrous effects: a process requiring certain privileges suddenly loses them causing exceptions, or a process that shouldn't have certain privileges (and is poorly written) does damage to the system upon gaining them.  Historical log data from the process may no longer make sense, and if the process has any kind of cache that was at all related to its user name (say a file in its home directory) or privileges that cache could become invalidated without the process having any way of knowing that.

The 'real' way to do this would be to just restart the processes as the new user.

Comment: So is the only way of doing it to stop all the process and start them from new user id ? All my files and cronjobs are all associated with `user1` which needs to be now running from `user2` . How can i do it in best possible way in least possible time as most of my process runs 24*7

Comment: Also consider that both user has same privileges.